# Is there always a telescopic series associated with a rational number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

Here is something I thought up while I was bored and my, erm, fish were busy:

> Given a rational number $p\in(0,1)$, are there always positive integers $n$, $c_m$, and $w_m$ such that $$p=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{\prod\limits_{m=1}^n (c_m k+w_m)}?$$ If so, how do you find these integers?

I got curious about this when I started playing around with [telescopic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). As you know, the good thing about them is that they are easily evaluated through clever rewriting of the general term, after which there is much cancellation, leaving behind a few terms that add up to the desired result.

That got me wondering on whether a rational number always has a telescopic series representation. I don't really know how this might be proven (and I'm not that good at math), so I wish somebody could enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: an example, $p=\frac37$, given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/177906/19341)...

Comment: @draks, I have seen that, but the numerators in that answer are $\neq 1$, while I am asking for a telescopic series whose general term has $1$ as the numerator. Otherwise, you can always just multiply whatever telescopic series with an appropriate rational factor.

Comment: ok, good luck and +1